# Backbone get not working with "this"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I just struggled to use underscore get with backbone collection.

```
var collection=Backbone.Collection.extend({
model:someModel,
getModelEntry : function(id){
 return this.get(id);

//returns undefined
}
})
```

attempt 2:

```
var collection=Backbone.Collection.extend({
     model:someModel,
    getModelEntry : function(id){
     var model = this.where({id:id})[0];
    //here I got model
     return model.get("attr");
    //returns undefined
    }
    });
```

whats wrong with using get in collection?

get is working perfect on instances!

```
var coll=new collection;

coll.get(id); //working fine
```

Comment: Mmm, that's strange, I made a quick jsfiddle and it works: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7gDN/) (check the console for the output).

Comment: `coll.getModelEntry(id)` returns `undefined`? Very strange..

Comment: checked that the idAttribute of your backbone model has not been set to something else than id ?

Comment: Can you share your model code, what IAattributeid you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine as far I could see. Check does the id of the model you're looking for exists in your collection. Add something like below and see what happens

```
    getModelEntry : function(id){            
            var model = this.get(id);
            if(model == undefined) {
                console.log("id: ",id);
                console.log("collection: ",JSON.stringify(this.models));
            } else {
               console.log(model.get('name'));                
            }        
        }
```